# Select all possible pairs of attributes in RapidMiner

Tags: rapidminer

I have a list where the total amount of attributes is unknown at first.

I want to concenate all pairs of attributes, without knowing how many of them are there.

There is a`Loop Attribute Subsets` Operator, but sadly there is no Output.

Currently my process looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="7.1.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.0.002" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="subprocess" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Data" width="90" x="45" y="75">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification" width="90" x="45" y="30">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;A&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;B&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;C&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" width="90" x="180" y="30">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;B&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;C&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;D&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (3)" width="90" x="315" y="30">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;D&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;A&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;B&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (4)" width="90" x="450" y="30">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;A&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;C&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;M&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (5)" width="90" x="585" y="30">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;C&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;M&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;M&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="148" name="Append" width="90" x="720" y="30"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="declare_missing_value" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Declare Missing Value" width="90" x="855" y="30">
            <parameter key="mode" value="nominal"/>
            <parameter key="nominal_value" value="M"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 2"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (3)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 3"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (4)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 4"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (5)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 5"/>
          <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_op="Declare Missing Value" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Declare Missing Value" from_port="example set output" to_port="out 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="extract_macro" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Extract Macro (2)" width="90" x="179" y="75">
        <parameter key="macro" value="num_attr"/>
        <parameter key="macro_type" value="number_of_attributes"/>
        <list key="additional_macros"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="rename_by_generic_names" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename by Generic Names (2)" width="90" x="313" y="75"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="multiply" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="124" name="Multiply (2)" width="90" x="179" y="300"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes (2)" width="90" x="380" y="210">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="|att1|att2"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="rename_by_generic_names" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename by Generic Names (5)" width="90" x="514" y="210"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes (3)" width="90" x="380" y="300">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="att1||att3"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes (4)" width="90" x="380" y="390">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="att2||att3"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="rename_by_generic_names" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename by Generic Names (3)" width="90" x="514" y="390"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="rename_by_generic_names" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename by Generic Names (4)" width="90" x="514" y="300"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_examples" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="103" name="Filter Examples (2)" width="90" x="648" y="210">
        <parameter key="condition_class" value="no_missing_attributes"/>
        <list key="filters_list"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_examples" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="103" name="Filter Examples (3)" width="90" x="648" y="300">
        <parameter key="condition_class" value="no_missing_attributes"/>
        <list key="filters_list"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_examples" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="103" name="Filter Examples (4)" width="90" x="648" y="390">
        <parameter key="condition_class" value="no_missing_attributes"/>
        <list key="filters_list"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_concatenation" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Concatenation (2)" width="90" x="782" y="390">
        <parameter key="first_attribute" value="att1"/>
        <parameter key="second_attribute" value="att2"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_concatenation" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Concatenation (3)" width="90" x="782" y="300">
        <parameter key="first_attribute" value="att1"/>
        <parameter key="second_attribute" value="att2"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_concatenation" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Concatenation (4)" width="90" x="782" y="210">
        <parameter key="first_attribute" value="att1"/>
        <parameter key="second_attribute" value="att2"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="124" name="Append (3)" width="90" x="916" y="255"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data" from_port="out 1" to_op="Extract Macro (2)" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Extract Macro (2)" from_port="example set" to_op="Rename by Generic Names (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename by Generic Names (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Multiply (2)" to_port="input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename by Generic Names (2)" from_port="original" to_port="result 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply (2)" from_port="output 1" to_op="Select Attributes (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply (2)" from_port="output 2" to_op="Select Attributes (3)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply (2)" from_port="output 3" to_op="Select Attributes (4)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename by Generic Names (5)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename by Generic Names (5)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Filter Examples (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes (3)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename by Generic Names (4)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes (4)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename by Generic Names (3)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename by Generic Names (3)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Filter Examples (4)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename by Generic Names (4)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Filter Examples (3)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Examples (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Generate Concatenation (4)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Examples (3)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Generate Concatenation (3)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Examples (4)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Generate Concatenation (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Concatenation (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Append (3)" to_port="example set 3"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Concatenation (3)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Append (3)" to_port="example set 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Concatenation (4)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Append (3)" to_port="example set 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Append (3)" from_port="merged set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one. The `Loop Subsets` operator doesn't return a single example set because it will create multiple different example sets each consisting of attributes made from combinations of the input attributes. To get round this, the `Recall` and `Remember` operators can be used to store running totals. The story isn't finished yet because it's usually the case that a single example set is required so this means some extreme gymnastics are needed to rename and join.

To cut a long story short, I've enclosed a standalone example process that illustrates all of this. It won't work without adaptation to your data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="7.0.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Iris" width="90" x="45" y="34">
    <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="multiply" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Multiply" width="90" x="45" y="136"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop_attribute_subsets" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Loop Subsets" width="90" x="179" y="34">
    <parameter key="exact_number_of_attributes" value="2"/>
    <parameter key="min_number_of_attributes" value="2"/>
    <parameter key="limit_max_number" value="true"/>
    <parameter key="max_number_of_attributes" value="2"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="log" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Log" width="90" x="112" y="34">
        <list key="log">
          <parameter key="Attributes" value="operator.Loop Subsets.value.feature_names"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="log_to_data" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Log to Data" width="90" x="112" y="238">
        <parameter key="log_name" value="Log"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="subprocess" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Subprocess" width="90" x="246" y="238">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="extract_macro" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Extract Macro" width="90" x="179" y="136">
        <parameter key="macro" value="remember"/>
        <parameter key="macro_type" value="data_value"/>
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="Attributes"/>
        <parameter key="example_index" value="1"/>
        <list key="additional_macros"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="clear_log" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Clear Log" width="90" x="380" y="136">
        <parameter key="log_name" value="Log"/>
        <parameter key="delete_table" value="true"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="in 1" to_port="out 1"/>
          <connect from_port="in 2" to_op="Extract Macro" to_port="example set"/>
          <connect from_op="Extract Macro" from_port="example set" to_op="Clear Log" to_port="through 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Clear Log" from_port="through 1" to_port="out 2"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 2" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 3" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 3" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="materialize_data" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Materialize Data" width="90" x="246" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="rename_by_generic_names" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename by Generic Names" width="90" x="380" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_concatenation" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Concatenation" width="90" x="380" y="136">
        <parameter key="first_attribute" value="att1"/>
        <parameter key="second_attribute" value="att2"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="380" y="238">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="att2|att1"/>
        <parameter key="invert_selection" value="true"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="rename" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename" width="90" x="514" y="34">
        <parameter key="old_name" value="att1_att2"/>
        <parameter key="new_name" value="%{remember}"/>
        <list key="rename_additional_attributes"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="handle_exception" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Handle Exception" width="90" x="514" y="136">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="recall" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Recall (2)" width="90" x="45" y="187">
        <parameter key="name" value="runningTotal"/>
        <parameter key="remove_from_store" value="false"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="join" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Join" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <list key="key_attributes">
          <parameter key="Play" value="Play"/>
        </list>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="remember" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Remember" width="90" x="246" y="187">
        <parameter key="name" value="runningTotal"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="in 1" to_op="Join" to_port="left"/>
          <connect from_op="Recall (2)" from_port="result" to_op="Join" to_port="right"/>
          <connect from_op="Join" from_port="join" to_op="Remember" to_port="store"/>
          <connect from_op="Remember" from_port="stored" to_port="out 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 2" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="remember" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Remember (2)" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <parameter key="name" value="runningTotal"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="in 1" to_op="Remember (2)" to_port="store"/>
          <connect from_op="Remember (2)" from_port="stored" to_port="out 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 2" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_port="example set" to_op="Log" to_port="through 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Log" from_port="through 1" to_op="Log to Data" to_port="through 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Log to Data" from_port="exampleSet" to_op="Subprocess" to_port="in 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Log to Data" from_port="through 1" to_op="Subprocess" to_port="in 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Subprocess" from_port="out 1" to_op="Materialize Data" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Materialize Data" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename by Generic Names" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename by Generic Names" from_port="example set output" to_op="Generate Concatenation" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Concatenation" from_port="example set output" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename" from_port="example set output" to_op="Handle Exception" to_port="in 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="subprocess" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Subprocess (2)" width="90" x="313" y="34">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="recall" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Recall" width="90" x="246" y="85">
        <parameter key="name" value="runningTotal"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Recall" from_port="result" to_port="out 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_in 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="join" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Join (2)" width="90" x="581" y="136">
    <list key="key_attributes"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Iris" from_port="output" to_op="Multiply" to_port="input"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply" from_port="output 1" to_op="Loop Subsets" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply" from_port="output 2" to_op="Join (2)" to_port="right"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop Subsets" from_port="example set" to_op="Subprocess (2)" to_port="in 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Subprocess (2)" from_port="out 1" to_op="Join (2)" to_port="left"/>
      <connect from_op="Join (2)" from_port="join" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="90"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Points to note

- The `Loop Subsets` operator is set to pick pairs of attributes
- Using `Log` and `Log to Data` inside `Loop Subsets` allows the current pair of attributes to be logged, transferred to an example set and then copied into a macro.
- Attributes are renamed to a common name, concatenated and then the result is renamed back to the original name.
- A running total example set is created by using `Join` to the previous iteration. The first time in, there is no previous iteration and this is handled by the `Handle Exception` operator.
- Outside the `Loop Subsets` operator, the running total example set is recalled inside a `Sub Process` to ensure the execution order comes out correctly.
- The running total is joined to the original data to make it easy to see if it worked or not.

One final point, the `Materialize Data` operator is required even though it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you Andrew,

I am actually learning a lot from that process. But I have a few questions, which will hopefully help me understand.

Within the `Loop Subsets` Subprocess, why do you call the `Results (Log)` Operator right after the `Log` Operator? 

How can you use the `Recall(2)(Recall)` Operator, without using the `Remember`Operator before?

And what is the `Remember (3)` Operator, right after the `Recall`Operator, within the `Subprocess` for?

Comment: I edited the process to simplify it and added some explanation. The first version did extra logging which isn't needed and there was an extra `Recall` which wasn't needed either.